# How to force jqxWindow to be topmost

Tags: javascript, topmost, jqxwidgets

I use js jqxWindow on my web page. They are  frames allowing to be moved, resized, and got focus.
But each time I select a jqxWindow, this becomes the topmost one.
I need to kept some other windows topmost. How to do that ?

Comment: There is a property called 'zIndex'. Usage is : $('#jqxWindow').jqxWindow({ zIndex: 99999}); But it does'nt works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only solution for this is to apply `bringToFront` in the opening code of the other windows to the window, which shall always be on top.